# Does iTunes connect converts rectangle shaped app icon to round shaped one by itself?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload app to app store. 
I have rectangle shaped app icon with 1024*1024 pixels. I have to upload a round shaped app icon in itunes connect.

Does iTunes connect converts the rectangle shaped icon to round shaped automatically? Or do i have to do the necessary changes?

Thanks
Jithendra

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2

Comment: but i gave this link first to you.

Comment: Yes. I can only vote you. If you have added this answers instead of comment, i could have accepted your answer.

Comment: there is answer too Young man ok do as you wish. '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this Document Provided By Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2)
Icons with visible backgrounds look best on the Home screen primarily because of the `rounded corners iOS adds`. This is because uniformly rounded corners ensure that all the icons on a user's Home screen have a consistent appearance that invites tapping.If you create an icon with a background that disappears when it's viewed on the Home screen, users don't see the rounded corners. Such icons often don't look tappable and tend to interfere with the orderly symmetry of the Home screen that users appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

All necessary rounding of the edges, gloss effects and etc will be automatically applied by Apple where necessary. This applies to all app icons. Bunty Madan has posted in their comment the link to Apple's details on the topic - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2